# Confidence interval for quantile regression using bootstrap, categorical variables

Tags: r, confidence-interval, quantile, quantile-regression

I am trying to get bootstrap confidence intervals for quantile regression . My regression response factors are mainly categorical variables. When I run the code boot.rq, I get the error below;

NAs introduced by coercionError in boot.rq.xy(x, y, U, tau) : 
  NA/NaN/Inf in foreign function call (arg 7)

Below is an example whereby I would like to calculate the confidence intervals for type;

```
library(car)
library(quantreg)
library(boot)
newdata<-Prestige
mod2 = rq(income ~ education+ prestige + women + type, data=newdata)
dat2 <- newdata[,c("education","women","prestige","census","type")]
mod3=boot.rq(cbind(1,dat2),newdata$income,tau=0.5, R=10000)
```

The illustration is from a previous discussion on this forum;

[Confidence interval for quantile regression using bootstrap](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46395907/confidence-interval-for-quantile-regression-using-bootstrap)